# Change text in file with data from an other file and write out to screen

Tags: powershell, replace

I would start with I was looking for answers but I could not find one.
The code is this but it reads in 1 line from the data.txt and after that all lines in message.txt.
The message.txt contains    strings and data.txt has these separeted with ';' like this:

Josh Adams;NYC 5th Avenue;18:25

Peter Nordmann;NCY 5th Avenue;20:00
...

```
    foreach ($dataLine in Get-Content .\data.txt){
    $data = $dataLine -split ';'
    foreach($line in Get-Content .\message.txt){
        $line.replace('<name>', $data[0])
        $line.replace('<place>', $data[1])
        $line.replace('<time>', $data[2])
    }
    Write-Output $line
    }
```

Comment: On screen it should print out the content is message.txt with the replaces with the 1st line of data.txt, after that the same with the 2nd and so on.

Comment: I forgot to put $line = $line.replace(...
Sorry to bother anyone now I just need to delete this post

Comment: If you want to update your question you should update/edit your question and not add comments. ;-)

Comment: You files seem to be CSV files. Why don't you treat them as such and use `Import-CSV` instead ot `Get-Content`? That would make your task easier. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just capture your searched text content to a variable, use that variable content to write to the new or the other file, using the normal built-in cmdlet(s)...

[Add-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-6)

or

[Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6)

.. using the append options.

Lastly, there are multiple ways to save content to a variable, for use elsewhere and output to the screen.

[3 ways to store and display PowerShell Variable simultaneously](https://ridicurious.com/2017/06/30/3-ways-to-store-display-results-infrom-a-powershell-variable-at-the-same-time/)

```
# Using -OutVariable parameter
Get-Process a* -OutVariable process

# PowerShell Variable squeezing
($process = Get-Process a*)

# Using Tee-Object Cmdlet
Get-Process a* | Tee-Object -Variable p
```